# Page numbers not getting displayed for the Table of contents in the downloaded document

Tags: document, xsl-fo

I need to show the page numbers for the Table of Contents in the word document(rtf). Below is the piece of snippet code which is not working. The left hand title are displayed properly and when we click on that it takes to the appropriate page but the page numbers are not getting displayed. Just for debugging purpose I tried generate-id() but it doesnt do anything.Any inputs on making this work would be appreciated.Thanks

```
<xsl:template match="html:td[contains(@class,'blabla')]">
    <xsl:variable name="refId" select="substring-after(parent::html:tr/@id,'toc_')" />
    <fo:table-cell border="none">
        <fo:block text-align-last="justify">
            <fo:basic-link internal-destination="{$refId}">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </fo:basic-link>        
            <xsl:text>&nbsp;</xsl:text>
            <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" leader-pattern-width="3pt" leader-length="20cm" />
            <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="{$refId}"/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This looks to me like an XSL-FO question, not an XSLT question, isn't it?  The SO tag is "xsl-fo".  If the generated XSL-FO is correct, it might even be an RTF question (what is generated from the XSL-FO) or a question depending on the engine you use to generate RTF from XSL-FO.

Comment: Yeah its an xsl:fo question and am guessing the xsl-fo mentioned above is incomplete or something needs to be added to show the page numbers on the toc in the downloaded document. I am trying to find the missing piece here. hope this makes sense

Comment: What is your page size? On A4, the leader length of 20 cm would put the page number outside the page boundary.